# Show 404 error if doesn't exist url

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with 404 error in CodeIgniter.I have in controller:

```
public function show($id = 0)
{
    $review = $this->site_reviews->get_review($id);


    if ($review)
    {
              .....
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
```

Now if I add to the end of link for example : /?id=13865 or /?id=42788?id=42788 all goes well...How to show_404()..Exist a solution?

Comment: Your question is not clear - you are saying all goes well but you want to show a 404?

Answer (score 0):

This case when your id is in codigniter format:

**$id=$this->uri->segment(3)//url:www.example.com/13865**

This case when you use core php concepts is get:

**$id=$_GET['id']//url:www.example.com?id=13865**

```
public function show($id = 0)
{
    $review = $this->site_reviews->get_review($id);


    if ($review)
    {
              .....
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
```

Comment: not clear so just got the solution which i derived for the problem